# libev ev_io_stop() does not close socket

Tags: c, sockets, libev

I have a server using libev
Whenever a client socket breaks the socket connection is stopped
using a code like this

```
ev_io_stop(loop, watcher);
```

Do I need to specifically call shutdown()  or close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling close() solved the issue.

I guess that would have helped if documented

Comment: Yes, because stopping watcher is a different action from a closing or shutting down a socket.